# Question about S.Lang's proof of Kummer's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I have a question about the proof of Kummer's Lemma in Serge Lang's *Cyclotomic fields* (i.e. Theorem 6.1). Let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\xi_p)$ the $p$-th cyclotomic field extension of $\mathbf{Q}$. Let $u$ be a unit in $K$. He first shows that it is unramified at the prime ideal $(\xi_p - 1)$ of $K$ .Then he states that $K(u^{1 / p})$ is "trivially unramified" at all other primes of $K$. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a typo in the question; I think you mean $K(u^{1/p})/K$ is unramified at the ideal over $(\zeta_p - 1)$.

To answer the question, the minimal polynomial of this extension certainly divides $x^p - u$, but that polynomial is separable mod $\lambda$ for any $\lambda \nmid p$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand - why would this be a problem if $x^p - u$ is separable mod $\lambda$?

Comment: @Steven an extension $L/K$ is unramified above a prime $\lambda$ of $K$ if a polynomial giving the extension is separable mod $\lambda$ (this isn't iff because O_L may not be generated by a root of this polynomial, but "if" is the direction you need). This in turn follows from the usual algorithm for determining prime decomposition in extensions of Dedekind domains (reduce minimal polynomial mod $\lambda$); see Lang's Algebraic Number Theory (or several other sources) if that's new to you.

Comment: I think I found the theorem you mentioned, but I still don't quite get it. I'll ask a new question about that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Primes ramified in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[n]{m})$ divide $mn$ by a simple computation of the discriminant $x^n - m$. Now lift the proof to $K$.

Comment: The first sentence of your comment is clear to me. About "lifting the proof to $K$" I am unsure. I guess one would have to use the discriminant formula for towers of extensions of number fields, but how can I deal with the norm-part?

Comment: Just replace ${\mathbb Q}$ by $K$ everywhere - there's no need to take norms. In your example, the ramified prime ideals divide $pu$, and that's all you need.